# Prevent combinational explosion in classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a project in which I have implemented a state machine framework in C++ based upon Miro Samek's statecharts framework (https://www.state-machine.com/).  In the basic design, there is a class called `StateMachine` from which all classes wishing to make use of state machine behavior inherit from. The `StateMachine` base class contains all of the "boiler plate" code to make a state machine work.

The state machine framework presented in Samek's book also supports additional features like: transitioning to history, deferred events, etc...  However, most of the state machines I would write do not need these features.

My first (bad) thought was to do something like:

```
class StateMachine;
class StateMachineWithHistory : public StateMachine;
class StateMachineWithDeferredEvents : public StateMachine;
```

There is an immediate problem with this if I want a state machine implementation to have both features.  I believe this type of problem is call "combinational explosion."

My second idea was to use virtual inheritance instead:

```
class StateMachine;
class StateMachineWithHistory : public virtual StateMachine;
class StateMachineWithDeferredEvents : public virtual StateMachine;

class MyStateMachine : public StateMachineWithHistory , public StateMachineWithDeferredEvents;
```

I ran a test and this seems to be a valid solution.  However, it makes me ask the question, what is the overhead of using virtual inheritance?  I assume it is the same as introducing virtual methods?

Is there an alternative (better) option I should consider?

**EDIT**

I want to clarify that the reason I thought of virtual inheritance was because, in my mind, what I am trying to express in words is the following:

> MyStateMachine is a StateMachine and also has the features of history
> and deferred events. A state machine with deferred events is a state
> machine.  A state machine with history is a state machine.

The "is a" wording usually implies inheritance. I suppose the other (less obvious to me) way to express this would be:

> MyStateMachine makes use of the features offered by a state machine, a deferred events, and history.  The deferred event and history features require the features offered by a state machine.

or

> MyStateMachine behaves like a state machine.

Comment: Mostly depend of interface/code you have. Decorator pattern might be a good alternative for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 From my understanding, is the decorator pattern sort of a runtime version of the idea of policies?

Comment: Virtual member functions don't cause the same overhead like virtual inheritance. These are two orthogonal features which may or may not be combined. For virtual member functions, a function table is used. (With the usual implementations, I'm aware of) it adds a bit memory footprint to each instance to address a function table and causes that virtual functions are called via that function table (i.e. an additional "trampoline jump"). Virtual inheritance means that multiple base classes are merged so that the resp. members are effectively stored once only.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat So, if I understand correctly, virtual inheritance by itself wouldn't actually add any runtime overhead?  I did read that it causes headaches when copying objects, but in my case, I don't need to copy, I am basically just inheriting additional features.

Comment: Enforcing a single instance of a base means its offset inside the greater derived object is no longer a run-time constant. Every access to that base requires a run-time resolution. There are no free lunches.

Comment: IMHO, virtual inheritance doesn't have such a good reputation and isn't used quite often. It's a little bit difficult to manage. On the other hand, `std::iostream` is based on virtual inheritance. I personally try to prevent virtual inheritance but sometimes it was my last resort and did its job. If you find something better use something better. ;-)